# Keyboard Shortcut CTRL+DEL calls CTRL+C

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I hope someone has an idea on how I can fix or at least discern what is happening on my windows system.
I am running windows 10 and I have noticed that whenever I hit the combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> on the keyboard, it immediately calls <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> straight after.
No idea what is going on

Thanks for the help in advanced.

Comment: It might be worth looking for any programs that could possibly be intercepting key presses. `Ctrl + C` is a common combination to stop command line execution.

Comment: How do you know it actually calls Ctrl+C?

Comment: @Anaksunaman do you have any advice what I can use to see this information? Could it also be some kind of hardware/bios thing perhaps?

Comment: @grawity I use Pycharm and when I was re-associating the CTRL-DEL shortcut, it would auto call CTRL-C, I tested it in other applications also so it isn't a Pycharm issue

Comment: I would say it's unlikely to be related to the BIOS in any way. Hardware is possible but I've never personally encountered anything like what you describe. Failing hardware might exhibit odd behaviors. Honestly, I would simply start disabling likely culprits and when see when the issue resolves itself. There are a few programs that can display key presses. I would grab one of those, then start closing programs running in the system tray and move on from there. It's probably worthwhile to throughly examine the settings of any running programs as well.